# Get user switch notification in Ubuntu and Kubuntu

Tags: 16.04, kubuntu, services, c++, user-management

I'm writing a daemon in C++ that needs to know when a User Switch event occurs on the desktop(not in a particular terminal). I would like to know if there is an API I can call or a file I can monitor to do this. The daemon needs to run on both Ubuntu and Kubuntu.

Ideally, I would like to be able to do this without polling but if that is the only possible way, I'm ok with that.

I've tried googling but did not find anything relevant. Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: I once did something similar from the shell to find out when the screensaver gets activated. Unfortunately I cannot find my scriptlet any more, nor do I recall the exact commands. But it had to do with the `dbus-monitor` command. It's a bit similar to inotifywait. Perhaps google for that. I'm pretty sure there's a C/C++ library as well. Try `dbus-monitor --system --monitor "type='signal'"` in a shell and see what messages appear to get an idea.

Comment: See also http://0pointer.net/blog/the-new-sd-bus-api-of-systemd.html

Comment: @PerlDuck Thanks to your suggestion I was able to use the dbus to get the user details. If you can post your comment as an answer I can accept it since I do not have the reputation to upvote your comment.